# Can anyone help me to understand three window in Meld diff tool

Tags: git, git-diff, meld, git-merge-conflict

While using `Meld` I am seeing three vertical side

On left `Test.txt.LOCAL.10512.txt`

In middle `Test.txt`

On Right `Test.txt.REMOTE.10512.txt`

Can anyone help me to understand these three window. and which one should i consider as final merged file ? I am not able find anything regarding this on internet.

Answer (score 4):

I use same tools (araxis merge). First file - your local file, second file - result what be after merge, the third file - file in git repository.

So your need change middle file and fix all conflict in it.

Sory for my bad english

Comment: So you are saying that file in the middle is the final one that will get after all merge

Comment: tell me something If i have something on LEFT window in green color SHall i move that on the middle window ?